# Reading in Year not as continuous but discrete on the x axis

Tags: r, axis-labels

I am having an issue with the year being read in as 2009.0, 2009.5, 2010, 2010.5, 2011

I tried changing the year to character and it just messed up the lines.

```r
ggplot(allom, aes(x= year, y= acidity, shape= cultivar, color= cultivar)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(vars(location))+
  labs(title = "Apple Acidity(mg/l malic acid) Between Location 1 & 2 ",
       subtitle = "2009-2011 ",
       caption = "source: Provided Data Set",
       y = "Acidity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

Resulting plots with decimals for year:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try `df$year <- as.integer(df$year)`. It will remove the decimal part though.

Comment: ggplot(allom, 
       aes(x= allom$year, y= acidity, shape= cultivar, color= cultivar)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(vars(location))+
  labs(title = "Apple Acidity(mg/l malic acid) Between Location 1 & 2 ",
       subtitle = "2009-2011 ",
       caption = "source: Provided Apple Data Set",
       y = "Acidity (mg/l malic acid)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
  xlab('Years')'

Comment: Warning messages:
1: Use of `allom$year` is discouraged. Use `year` instead. 
2: Use of `allom$year` is discouraged. Use `year` instead.

Comment: Am I just putting the allom$year in the wrong place?

Comment: x = as.integer(year)

Comment: For some reason that is not working. Still giving me decimals in my years.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
df$year <- ceiling(df$year)
```